# .net core web app authorize failure not redirecting

Tags: asp.net-core, claims-based-identity

i have added policy for checking if the claims exists or not. On authorization failure app is crashing with 502.3 error while debugging. Its not redirecting to the intended page.

services.AddAuthorization(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("NCMSUSERS", policy => policy.RequireClaim("groups", "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxxxx-xxx"));
            });

Comment: Can you post stacktrace as well?

Comment: Never mind i had my routing all messed up thanks